# In Lua, is there a limitation to the number of objects/tables that can be deterministically managed by the garbage collector?

Tags: memory, memory-management, lua, garbage-collection, free

For reference, the Scenarios described below were executed using the following:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
- top "procps-ng 3.3.12"
- Lua 5.3.3 Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

Each "Scenario" below demonstrates results of the following steps:

1. Capture "lua5.3" initial process resource usage from "top"
2. In "lua5.3", allocate ~16GB from the heap
3. Capture "lua5.3" new process resource usage from "top" to show that 16GB was allocated
4. In "lua5.3", mark root object for deletion and then call "collectgarbage()"
5. Capture "lua5.3" final process resource usage from "top" to show effect of "collectgarbage()"

For each scenario, compare the initial process resource usage, "allocated" process resource usage, and the final process resource usage after "collectgarbage().  Scenario 1 shows that the "allocated" 16GB is **NOT** freed after garbage collection.  Scenario 2 and 3 show that **some** of the "allocated" 16GB is freed after garbage collection. Scenario 4 shows that **all** of the "allocated" 16GB is freed after garbage collection.  Scenarios 1 through 4 differ only in the number of objects (i.e. tables) used during allocation, where Scenario 1 uses the most tables (128*1024), and Scenario 4 uses the least (1).  Hence, it appears that the Lua 5.3.3 garbage collection has a limitation on the number of objects it can truly manage, or there is a defect in Lua's memory management.

In short, Lua's garbage collection is not showing deterministic behavior with memory management. If a large number of tables are created, the memory usage associated with those tables may never be returned to the heap as managed by the operating system, when the memory is no longer needed in Lua. However, if a small number of tables are created, the memory usage associated with those tables seem to ALWAYS be returned to the heap as managed by the operating system, when the memory is no longer needed in Lua.

Why is the memory management behavior in Lua not consistent/deterministic?

**NOTE**: For each scenario, calling collectgarbage("count") after collectgarbage() shows that lua5.3 has properly cleaned up all garbage, whereas using "top" shows that is not always the case. Hence, "top" is used here to show the true behavior of Lua's garbage collection.

## Scenario 1: Lua collectgarbage() does not free memory used

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22866 user      20   0   18152   3140   2840 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lua5.3

> collectgarbage("count")
22.8759765625

> a = {} for i=0,256*1024 do a[i] = {} for j=0,4*1024*1024 do a[i][j] = i*j end end

> collectgarbage("count")
16803927.791016

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22866 user      20   0 16.053g 0.016t   2868 S   0.0 51.3   0:38.97 lua5.3

> a = nil collectgarbage()

> collectgarbage("count")
25.29296875

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22866 user      20   0 16.049g 0.016t   2868 S   0.0 51.3   0:39.08 lua5.3
```

## Scenario 2: Lua collectgarbage() frees half of memory used

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22958 user      20   0   18152   3200   2916 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lua5.3

> collectgarbage("count")
22.8759765625

> a = {} for i=0,128*1024 do a[i] = {} for j=0,8*1024*1024 do a[i][j] = i*j end end

> collectgarbage("count")
16790679.791016

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22958 user      20   0 16.284g 0.016t   2944 S   0.0 52.0   0:39.79 lua5.3

> a = nil collectgarbage()

> collectgarbage("count")
23.1826171875

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
22958 user      20   0 8422324 8.018g   2944 S   0.0 25.6   0:40.50 lua5.3
```

## Scenario 3: Lua collectgarbage() frees almost all memory used

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23127 user      20   0   18152   3192   2904 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lua5.3

> collectgarbage("count")
22.8759765625

> a = {} for i=0,64*1024 do a[i] = {} for j=0,16*1024*1024 do a[i][j] = i*j end end

> collectgarbage("count")
16784151.791016

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23127 user      20   0 16.275g 0.016t   2932 S   0.0 52.0   0:41.22 lua5.3

> a = nil collectgarbage()

> collectgarbage("count")
23.1826171875

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23127 user      20   0   25900  10992   2932 S   0.0  0.0   0:41.81 lua5.3
```

## Scenario 4: Lua collectgarbage() frees all memory used

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23771 user      20   0   18152   3204   2920 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lua5.3

> collectgarbage("count")
22.8759765625

> a = {} for i=0,0 do a[i] = {} for j=0,1024*1024*1024 do a[i][j] = i*j end end

> collectgarbage("count")
16777241.969727

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23771 user      20   0 16.017g 0.016t   2948 S   0.0 51.2   0:38.97 lua5.3

> a = nil collectgarbage()

> collectgarbage("count")
23.17578125

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23771 user      20   0   18152   3364   2948 S   0.0  0.0   0:40.80 lua5.3
```

## Update

After additional testing, it does appear that the number of objects (i.e. tables) managed in Lua affects the behavior of Lua's garbage collection. Specifically, if the number of tables being managed by Lua is less than 256 (this seems to be the threshold), the memory will be returned to the operating system's heap after garbage collection. As the number of objects grows above 256 (inclusive), Lua's memory management begins to exhibit different behavior as it holds on to more memory for internal reuse after its garbage collection. Scenario 1 above shows the most dramatic affect of Lua holding onto memory after garbage collection, and Scenario 4 shows the least affect.

**Note:** The Example results are not deterministic; that is, other execution in Lua may affect the behavior of Lua's garbage collection. For the most deterministic results, launch a new Lua process for each test.

For illustration, the following examples continuously allocate, populate, and deallocate a table of tables, printing out the following from the Lua process: iteration, preMemoryUsage (after allocation), preMemoryUsagePercent, postMemoryUsage (after deallocation), postMemoryUsagePercent.

## Example Program: Change numberOfTables as Desired

```lua
numberOfTables = 255 -- Example 1: 255; Example 2: 256

function getMemoryPercent()
  handle = io.popen("v=`ps -p $PPID -o pmem= | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/ *//g'`; echo -n $v")
  memoryPercent = handle:read("*a")
  handle:close()

  return memoryPercent
end

socket = require("socket")

print("#", "preMemUsage", "%", "postMemUsage", "%")

iteration = 0

while true
do
  a = {}
  
  for i = 1,numberOfTables
  do
    a[i] = {}

    for j = 1,math.floor(256*1024*1024/numberOfTables)
    do
      a[i][j] = i*j
    end
  end

  preMemoryUsage = collectgarbage("count")
  preMemoryUsagePercent = getMemoryPercent()

  a = nil
  collectgarbage()

  postMemoryUsage = collectgarbage("count")
  postMemoryUsagePercent = getMemoryPercent()

  iteration = iteration + 1

  print(iteration, preMemoryUsage, preMemoryUsagePercent, postMemoryUsage, postMemoryUsagePercent)

end
```

## Example 1: Results for numberOfTables=255

```
#       preMemUsage     %       postMemUsage     %
1       8355905.0869141 25.4    47.240234375     0.0
2       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
3       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
4       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
5       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
6       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
7       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
8       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
9       8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
10      8355905.1972656 25.4    47.322265625     0.0
```

## Example 2: Results for numberOfTables=256

```
#       preMemUsage     %       postMemUsage     %
1       4194369.0205078 12.8    47.119140625     0.0
2       4194369.1308594 12.8    47.201171875     12.8
3       4194369.1035156 12.8    47.173828125     12.5
4       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
5       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
6       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
7       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
8       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
9       4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
10      4194369.1318359 12.8    47.2021484375    12.4
```

Comment: Probably, collected memory is available to other Lua objects, but still has not been returned to OS.  Can you repeat the tests using double invocation of `collectgarbage()`?  Can you repeat the tests using `collectgarbage("count")` to get the memory usage instead of executing `top`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I updated with the information you requested. Repeated calls to collectgarbage() result in no different behavior. Yes, at first I thought that this was a Lua "virtual machine" type behavior which allows Lua to obtain memory from the OS and then just manage it internally. But then I realized using "top" that this behavior was different when I used a small number of tables. Also, when using Lua within a C program, this is a problematic memory management issue for the "C/Lua" process; the memory used in Lua is not always "freed" such that the "C" portion can "reuse" the memory.

Comment: Maybe it's not Lua's fault, because Lua uses standard memory allocator from C library.  The same behavior should be seen if you work with C heap instead of Lua heap.  And this means the memory (which is not returned to OS) may be available for your C program.

Comment: I performed a similar test using just C, using calloc() and free(); so far, this testing has shown that the memory is returned to the heap, where "top" shows the memory as being available. For the Lua side, it does seem that I can continue to "reuse" the allocated memory within Lua. But as I said, there are circumstances where that memory may not be able to be re-used by C in a C/Lua mixed process.

Comment: You'd better post it on Lua mailing list.